# Are "avoir besoin de" and "devoir" interchangeable in the following sentence?

Tags: grammaire, usage, verbes

First sentence:

> On a besoin d'apprendre les mots parce qu'ils sont très important.

Second sentence:

> On doit apprendre les mots parce qu'ils sont très important.

I am a bit confused because in English both "need to" and "must" would work in this context. I was wondering if this is also the case in French?

Comment: They do not mean the same in English, and so don't they in French: see  [What's the difference between "avoir besoin de" and "devoir"](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/22868/whats-the-difference-between-avoir-besoin-de-and-devoir)

Comment: Side question: should it be "importants" here, in this post? Do adjectives agree when they're later in the sentence rather than directly attached to the noun?

Comment: @Aerovistae Quite right - it should agree.

Comment: @jlliagre Which English translations do you have in mind? Need to vs. have to? I would say they're the same in this context - which is probably why they've led to mistakenly thinking the French is also the same. I'm actually hesitant about "avoir besoin de" at all in this context!

Comment: @LukeSawczak I was thinking about *we need to* vs *we must*. While they are very close in this context, I still believe they are not strictly equivalent. *Avoir besoin* is about usefulness while *devoir* is about something imposed (even if self-imposed). Both of the OP sentences might be heard in French.

Comment: @jlliagre - and because this reads as other-imposed either way (to me anyway), I see them as either functionally the same or "avoir besoin" as less appropriate. Maybe the exact nuance in French escapes me. Or my imagination for this scenario :)

Comment: @LukeSawczak The meanings overlap a lot but I still feel there is a nuance. I would say a hard working student is more likely to say *avoir besoin* because learning words is important to improve him/herself (personal goal) than an average one for whom learning words is important to meet the requirements (external goal).

Comment: @jlliagre I think you're right. For some reason I misread it as more in the category of "On doit conjuguer le verbe ainsi", where the personal stake would make less sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context, I would consider both sentences as equivalent. They both carry the idea that "apprendre les mots" is an obligation and the slight difference in meaning is not important here.